# How to prevent the back button from being disabled (by Javascript)?

Tags: firefox, cache

From time to time, I am encountering web sites which disable the back button in Firefox. I suppose this is done by Javascript.

Is there a way to prevent the back button from being disabled (perhaps some setting in about:config)?

I know that navigating back can break functionality, especially in single page applications, but however, in some cases, I'd really like to do that even if the respective website tries to keep me from it.

During my research, I have found a lot of questions and answers where the problem was the opposite one (i.e. "How do I disable the back button by Javascript?") and a lot of questions and answers where the problems was how to disable the `<Backspace>` key in Firefox.

But I found only [one question from 2014](https://superuser.com/questions/718013/prevent-programmers-from-adding-functionality-to-the-back-button-in-browsers) where the OP also wanted to prevent websites from tampering with the classical behavior of the back button. This question is six years old and has not been answered in a satisfying way, so I felt I could ask again.

Comment: There are add-ons such as *uBlock Origin* that can disable *all* JavaScript on a *per site* basis. However, that might keep some sites from working.